# Dunn's test null hypothesis

Tags: dunn-test

According to this link:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/dunn-test/info

The null hypothesis for the two group Dunn's test is that one group does not stochastically dominate the other.  Is this correct?  Immediately following this claim, a statement of the null hypothesis is given in probability notation that does not seem to me to be equivalent to stochastic dominance.